# C# Nunit error - MVP architecture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, nunit

I'm trying to write a unit test for a sample project that uses the MVP architecture.
When I run the test, I have the following error message:

> UnitTests.Tests.testCopy:
>   Expected: "Testing ..."
>   But was: null

I post below the snippets I did:

```
namespace Copy
{
    public interface IView
    {
        string Copy { get; set; }
        string Original { get; }
        event EventHandler Changed;
    }

    public class Presenter
    {
        private IView view;
        public Presenter(IView view)
        {
            this.view = view;
            this.view.Changed += new EventHandler(OnChanged);
        }

        public void OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            view.Copy = view.Original;
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form, IView
    {
        private Presenter presenter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            presenter = new Presenter(thisIView);
            this.t_originalviewMock.TextChanged += OnChanged;
        }

        public string Original
        {
            get { return t_originalMockInstance).Text; }
        }

        public string Copy
        {
            get { return t_copy.Text; }
            set { t_copy.Text = value;}
        }

        private void OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Changed != null)
                Changed(sender, e);
        }

        public event EventHandler Changed;
    }
}
```

Unit test code:

```
namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        private DynamicMock viewMock;
        private Presenter presenter;

        [SetUp]
        public void setup()
        {
            viewMock = new DynamicMock(typeof(IView));
            presenter = new Presenter((IView)viewMock.MockInstance);
        }

        [Test]
        public void testCopy()
        {
            viewMock.ExpectAndReturn("get_Original", "Testing ...");
            viewMock.Expect("get_Cpoy");
            Assert.AreEqual("Testing ...", 
                ((IView)viewMock.MockInstance).Copy);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I'm trying to test that a change in Original textBox, leads to a change in Copy textBox."*

Here's how you should set up your test then:

1. Tell view mock to raise `Changed` event
2. Tell view mock to return `"Testing ..."` upon call to `get_Original` property getter
3. Tell view mock you're expecting call to `Copy` setter with `"Testing ..."` value
4. Verify mock expectations

I'm not sure whether *raising events* is possible with NUnit.Mocks. Judging by fairly tiny API, I'd say no. Yet you can go around this problem by invoking event handler directly (since it's public anyways):

```
viewMock.ExpectAndReturn("get_Original", "Testing ...");
viewMock.Expect("set_Copy", "Testing ...");

presenter.OnChanged(viewMock, EventArgs.Empty);

// here we verify expectations set on mock object; 
// that Copy setter was called with "Testing ..." value
viewMock.Verify();
```

You can see that this test indeed works by simply changing `set_Copy` expected value to something else than `"Testing ..."` - it will fail with appropriate message.

#### Mocking frameworks sidenote

Any reason you're using NUnit.Mocks instead of more serious mocking framework? Give [FakeItEasy](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy/), [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or [RhinoMocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) a look.

This is how your test *could* look like if you'd used FakeItEasy instead:

```
[Test]
public void WhenViewChangedEventIsRaised_PresenterSetsCopyProperty()
{
    var viewMock = A.Fake<IView>();
    var presenter = new Presenter(viewMock);
    A.CallTo(() => viewMock.Original).Returns("Testing ...");

    viewMock.Changed += Raise.With(EventArgs.Empty).Now;

    Assert.AreEqual(viewMock.Copy, "Testing ...");
}
```

Note that problems like typing `Cpoy` instead of `Copy` immediately go away. Not to mention you won't have to make your event handlers exposed in public API.

Comment: I'm trying to test that a change in Original textBox, leads to a change in Copy textBox.

If I try this:
        [Test]
        public void testCopy()
        {
            viewMock.ExpectAndReturn("get_Original", "Testing ...");
            viewMock.ExpectAndReturn("get_Copy", "Incorrect...");

        } 

the test doesn't fail.

Comment: @davidhale: Yeah I see what you're trying to accomplish now. See my edit #2.

Comment: That's it. Thank you for your help.
I'll also have a look at FakeItEasy and RhinoMocks.

Comment: @davidhale: You're welcome. I've updated FakeItEasy test example - you can check how much more natural it *"sounds"*, as compared to NUnitMocks one. Not to mention, you can then keep your Presenter event handlers private. Good luck!